# Regular expression: capture group might not exist. How do I write it?

Tags: regex

Here are some examples of the strings I need to parse:

```
1 - Cream Soda (0.99)
5 - Potato Chips (2.50)
12 - Atlantic Salmon
```

I want to capture the first numeral, the product name and the price including parentheses. Sometimes the price and associated parentheses don't exist.

I came up with this regex:

```
/(\d+)\s+-\s*(.+)\s+(\(.*\))/
```

which works only when all three groups exist. I also tried this:

```
/(\d+)\s+-\s*(.+)\s+(\(.*\))?/
```

but its not any better.

**How do I make the third capture group optional?**

This is in javascript if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap the trailing part with an optional non-capturing group and the pattern needs to be wrapped with anchors:

```
/^(\d+)\s+-\s*(.*?)(?:\s+(\([^()]+\)))?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IytHHB/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)`  - Group 1 capturing the first 1 or more digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars but as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(\([^()]+\)))?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(\([^()]+\))` - Group 3 capturing `(`, 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`, then `)`
- `$`  - end of string.

```js
var strs = ["1 - Cream Soda (0.99)", "5 - Potato Chips (2.50)", "12 - Atlantic Salmon"];
var re = /^(\d+)\s+-\s*(.*?)(?:\s+(\([^()]+\)))?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  var m = re.exec(s);
  if (m) {
    console.log("1: " + m[1] + ", 2: " + m[2] + (m[3] ? ", 3: " + m[3] : ""));
  }
}
```

Comment: I love the power and flexibility of regex, but its definitely not my forte. This does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You can make 2nd group lazy and use line end as alternate match in 3rd group:

```
(\d+)\s+-\s*(.+?)\s*(\(.*\)|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0HC9z/2)